# ExtendedMembershipProvider.GetUserIDfromOauth returns what user ID?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I'm trying to customize my own implementation of ExtendedMembershipProvider.  I have no idea what the GetUserIDFromOauth method is supposed to do?  I see it is throwing an exception by default, and that it is supposed to return the user ID from the open auth provider.

I fail to see how this is supposed to be done, unless this means find if that user exists in the system?  Is that it's purpose?  I find the lack of documentation confusing...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetUserIdFromOAuth` is a method used by `ExtendedMembershipProvider` class to find `User.Id` in your table of users in your web application database based on `Provider` and `ProviderUserId` that you get from OAuth or OpenId Provider. After getting `Provider` and `ProviderUserId` data for a specified user, you need to save it in your database.

It returns `throw new NotImplementedException();` by default. You need to implement this method to return an integer of your `User.Id` from your application database.

This is a sample implementation:

```cs
    public override int GetUserIdFromOAuth(string provider, string providerUserId)
    {
        using (var context = new YourApplicationEntities())
        {
            // Try to find user with certain Provider and ProviderUserId
            var user = context.Users.SingleOrDefault(
                           q => q.Provider == provider &&
                           q.ProviderUserId == providerUserId
            );

            if (user != null)
            {
                 return user.Id;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

This implementation assumed that you have `Provider` and `ProviderUserId` field in your `User` table. If this information saved in a different table, you just need to modify the LINQ to return the desired result.